# Flex Mobile validateNow() not working

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, stage

I have a long and busy for loop which is supposed to addElement on the stage iteratively. Since it takes several seconds to execute the whole loop (i=1:N), i just want to refresh the stage at each loop so that the output is displayed before the loop reaches its final point (N). each iteration should add a displayable element before the next iteration begins.
For this i wrote the following

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 280; i++){
 addElement(...);
 validateNow();
}
```

but it is not working like i want. anyone having solution please?

Comment: Maybe if you explained what you were trying to accomplish; we can direct you to a better solution to your problem.  I would not expect adding 280 items to the stage in a Flex Mobile App is going to be very effective.  Perhaps you would be better suited using a List based control which won't need to render all 280 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide up this lengthy work so that it can occur over multiple frames. Flash/Flex do not update the screen when your code is executing. Have a look at the [elastic race track](http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/18/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/) for Flash to help understand why. The Flex component life cycle adds another layer on top of that as well. By the way, calling `validateNow()` can be computationally expensive, possibly making your loop take longer :)

There are a number of ways to break up the work in the loop.

Here's a simple example using [callLater()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#callLater%28%29):

```
private function startWorking():void
{
    // create a queue of work (whatever you are iterating over)
    // in your loop you're counting to 280, you could use a
    // simple counter variable here instead
    var queue:Array = [ a, b, c];
    callLater(doWork, [ queue ] );
}

private function doWork(workQueue:Array):void
{
    var workItem:Object = workQueue.shift();
    // do expensive work to create the element to add to screen
    addElement(...);
    if (workQueue.length > 0)
        callLater(doWork, workQueue);
}
```

You may want to process more than 1 item at a time. You could also do the same thing using the ENTER_FRAME event instead of `callLater()` (in essence, this is what `callLater()` is doing).

**References**:

- [validateClient() docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/ILayoutManager.html#validateClient%28%29), calling validateNow() results in a call to this expensive method